# does not contain definition and no extension method error

Tags: c#, web-services

Getting the following error when trying to call my web service method that I created called `AddCustomer`. It is underlining AddCustomer when I do `pxy.AddCustomer(txtLogin.Text)`

> 'AuctionService' does not contain a definition for 'AddCustomer' and no extension method 'AddCustomer' accepting a first argument of type 'AuctionService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or  an assembly reference?)

Web-Services code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using Utilities;

namespace Project4WS
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for AuctionService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
  public class AuctionService : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public void AddCustomer(String Name)
    {
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand();
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCommand.CommandText = "AddCustomer";

        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theName", Name);
        DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
        DataSet myDataSet = objDB.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCommand);            
    }
  }
}
```

Button click code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Project4WS;

namespace Project4
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnNewUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        AuctionSvcPxy.AuctionService pxy = new AuctionSvcPxy.AuctionService();

        pxy.AddCustomer(txtLogin.Text);

        Session["Customer"] = txtLogin.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Change the access modifier of the method `AddCustomer` from `protected` to `public`

Comment: Still getting the same error when I change it to public

Answer (score 0):

`Project4WS` and `Project4` are two different namespaces. So the `protected void AddCustomer` method can't be accessed in the `btnNewUser_Click` method. Make the access modifier `public` for the `AddCustomer` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the access modifier of the method `AddCustomer` from protected to public